# Clicking Google Open ID still uses old Google OpenID URL

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid, google

I cleared my cache last night and had to log back into the trilogy this morning for the first time in a long time. As outlined in [Google Offers Named OpenIDs](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/) I had previously switched the sites to use a named OpenID from Google. Unfortunately, the select OpenID provider on the trilogy sites still default to the old random hash Google OpenID. Not sure if there is a way to provide a good user experience that would result in people using the new Google OpenID but it would be preferable to the current method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login page now has Google Profiles (should it be called Google Accounts?) in the secondary row of icons at the end.

Comment: Not sure I think Google Profile sums things up. Though not sure you want the underscore in the title text....

Comment: it's tied to the code path -- that's used for the image that is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can type your Google OpenID URL manually:

> `http://www.google.com/profiles/<username>`

Since named OpenIDs are still opt-in for Google accounts, I don't know if it would be safe to do it yet, or if there is even a way to implement it.