# Could Google Profiles get a "big button" for login?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, login, google-openid

By "Big Button" I mean one of the same size as the Google button.

This would be good for 2 reasons.

1. It would encourage users to investigate and use Profiles, which would allow them to take advantage of the unique per-domain qualities. At the moment Profiles seems like a second class citizen.
2. You'd actually know it was *there*. Especially as the giant "standard Google" button makes you think that it's not worth looking further. (And I'm clearly not the only one who found this, as this exists: [Clicking Google Open ID still uses old Google OpenID URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34600/clicking-google-open-id-still-uses-old-google-openid-url)

It makes sense for a further reason; if Big Buttons are associated with the most popular account types, and Google Profiles uses the same account as "standard Google", it makes sense to promote it to the big leagues.

Comment: People are going to use the openid that is easiest and most familiar for them. The rare few will actually care about this.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know the login page is that sophisticated. (I'd recommend learning your OpenID URL, to avoid surprises like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34110/it-should-be-possible-to-log-in-in-the-middle-of-writing-a-question-without-losing-it)

Comment: @Changeling: so where's the Facebook Connect? ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - [There](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44618/what-can-we-learn-from-quora) :-]

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the buttons were set up based on the number of actual users on Stack Overflow with each specific OpenID provider.  So you'll have a better case if you can show that a lot of people actually use Google Profiles to log in.

Comment: Well, that's catch-22. The big buttons encourage use.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with this, since I prefer the static Google URL, there are quite a few people who consider Google's unique ID per site to be more secure than a universally static ID. I believe they would probably prefer that be the "big button" for login.